# new theme activation

Tags: magento-1, theme, template, upgrade

I am activating a new theme on a page that has a previous premium theme so now when I click on "activate", it shows me this error:

[image]

And I have 2 options:

- Leave as is
- Override

I do not want to lose any of the data/products that I have already on my store. I just want to update the template.

Which option do I choose?

Answer (score 0):

The message refers to "pages", so the previous installation of the theme included CMS pages ("Impresoras 3D", etc.) and the update has new versions of these pages.

If you ever changed anything on the mentioned pages, choose "leave as is", if not you may choose "override" to get the new version. **This does not affect your products or other configuration.**